# Describe for LISP-Macros

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have used CLISP for some time now, and I'd say, that I finally came to "understand" macros. Now I have one question here:
Is there something similar to describe for functions but for macros?
I would like to put a docstring in my macro so that someone can look at it using a "describe-esk" function / macro on my macro.
If that wasn't clear enough, maybe this code example will clear it up for you:

```
(defmacro while (test &body body)
  "sexier while loop - usage: (while (< x 10) (princ x) (setf x (+ x 1)))"
  (list 'loop 'while test 'do (cons 'progn body)))

(describe-macro 'while)
#=>sexier while loop - usage: (while (< x 10) (princ x) (setf x (+ x 1)))
#=>args: test, body
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try `(describe 'while)`?

Comment: Or `(describe (macro-function 'while))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(documentation <x> 'function)` will provide you with the documentation of `<x>` as a function or macro:

```
> (documentation 'collecting 'function)
"Collect things into a list forwards.

Within the body of this macro The form `(COLLECT THING)' will collect
THING into the list returned by COLLECTING.  COLLECT is a local
function so can be passed as an argument, or returned.  COLLECT
returns its argument. See WITH-COLLECTORS for which this COLLECTING is
now a shim"
```

`describe` may also tell you useful things.  Typically programming environments like SLIME will also have all sorts of useful help available.  I don't know SLIME very well, but in LW the `Show Documentation` command when the cursor is over `collecting` pops up a window which shows

```
Documentation for (defmacro collecting):
Arguments: (&body forms)
<docstring as above>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`documentation`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm#documentation) function:

```
(documentation 'while 'function)
```

The `function` type is used for any name that's used in the function position of an expression, so it's used for functions, macros, and special operators.

Comment: for me the above returns nil :/

Comment: Isn't it the same as the answer you accepted?

Comment: @Barmar: yes, it is.  Person should really have accepted your answer, we must have written them  simultaneously...

Comment: @tfb But they also said it doesn't work, so why did they accept yours? Unless it's because you also suggested `describe`.

Comment: @Barmar: yes, I don't understand.  I think your answer is as good as mine, so ... well.  (Also *you* suggested `describe` which was why I added it...)

Comment: To clear this up, (documentation 'while 'fuction) did return nil for me. (describe 'while) did give a lot of output. In this output there was the following:
Documentation as a FUNCTION:
sexier while loop - usage: (while (< x 10) (princ x) (setf x (+ x 1)))

Comment: @L0ren2 -- if you type at the REPL what you typed in your comment: `(documentation 'while 'fuction)`, then will you probably see `NIL` returned, perhaps with a warning message, because `fuction` is not a known type. If you typed correctly `(documentation 'while 'function)`, you should see the same docstring that `describe` shows.

Comment: OMG I had a typo xD this was indeed the reason for me favouring the first answer :P